# Statistical framework for using MSE for linear classification

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood

We learned in class to use  a linear  model to to predict a real target value y. We made the assumption that $$ y = w^Tx + w_0 + \epsilon $$  where $x$ is the input vector,$w$ is the vector of the linear model parameters and $\epsilon$ is  a Gaussian distributed error. The professor showed us that since $y|x$ is a Gaussian random variable, maximizing the  likelihood( for $w$) is actually minimizing MSE namely minimizing

$$ \frac{1}{N}  \sum_{i=1}^N (y_i - (w^Tx_i + w_0 ))^2 $$
for $w$. This is all good.

But now he said that minimizing the MSE expression above is also valid for a binary  classification problem where $ y \in \{-1,1\} $. What is the statistical justification for this ? it is clear that $ y = w^Tx + w_0 + \epsilon $ does not hold any more and $y|x$ is not a Gaussian random variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validity comes from the close relationship between linear regression and linear discriminant analysis (LDA) for two classes. This result is detailed in [ESL](https://hastie.su.domains/Papers/ESLII.pdf) Section 4.3 and Exercise 4.2, whose solution is available online. To sum up, when there are only two classes and when the numbers of observations from both classes coincide, the least square classification of $y\in\{-1,1\}$ by solving the MSE criteria produces the same decision as the LDA.